# Should I uniform different API calls to a single format before caching?

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, memcached

The problem is that I am recreating the social media widget/icons on http://about.me/bluedaniel (thats me).

Anyhow there can be up to 6 or 7 different API calls on the page and obviously I am caching them, at the moment with Memcached.

The question is, as they arrive in various formats and sizes (fb-json, linkedin-xml, wordpress-rss etc), should I universally format/convert them before storing it in the cache.

At present I have recreated the html widget and then stored that, but I worry about saving huge blocks of html in the cache as it doesn't seem that smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing IO(disc) is expensive. That's why you should have a copy of the data in memory(memcached). But when you have a single data representation in memory then you can without almost any effort do the conversion because it is CPU-bound(CPU is not slowing you down) as long as your not touching the disc.

Comment: well at the moment it comes in whatever format (xml/json/rss) and I create the html output from that. You think it would be faster to convert everything to json(?) cache and work from there?

Comment: the json parser is probably going to be fastest because most modern browser have native json parser on board which is lightning fast!

Comment: so a trade off in time spent converting everything to json the first time, then next time cache comes streaming out of the blocks(cache). So I should only save the json api result or the outputted html widget?

Comment: I would store json in memory and do the other conversion via PHP/cpu. You could for example create html from json on the client using javascript. json also uses less memory then some other data types like for example xml.

Comment: ok going to give that a try and see what the difference is like. I'll leave the question open for a little while yet...